# Error on provided shape, expected (1200000) and actual (400000) tensor values are different

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow.js, jimp

Is there any way to have the input image values match the expected values? The input image I know for a fact is 800px in width, 500px in height, and is colored (meaning 3 channels), so the shape should be [800,500,3].
However, I receive the error below:

The error: `Error: Based on the provided shape, [800,500,3], the tensor should have 1200000 values but has 400000`

Is there any way to give the image a value of 1200000, or a way to adjust the shape to 400000 but still retain the 800x500 size with 3 channels?

The code:

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const fs = require(`fs`)
const Jimp = require(`jimp`)

const image = `./1-1.png`

const imageWidth = 800;
const imageHeight = 500;
const imageChannels = 3;

const getData = async function (path) {
  const data = [];
  const image = await Jimp.read(path);
  await image
      .scan(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, (x, y, idx) => {
        let v = image.bitmap.data[idx + 0];
        data.push(v / 255);
      });
  return data;
};

const createImage = async (data) => {
  const imTen = tf.tensor(data, [imageWidth, imageHeight, 3]);
  const inTen = imTen.expandDims();
  return inTen;
}

const main = async () => {
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file:///retake/savedmodels/model.json');
  model.summary();

  const a = await getData(image)
  const b = await createImage(a)

  const tfImage = b
  console.log(im)

  const prediction = model.predict(tfImage);
  prediction.print();
}
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> The input image I know for a fact is 800px in width, 500px in height, and is colored (meaning 3 channels)

Check return value of your `getData` method since it seems its returning grayscale image - that would match 400,000 instead of expected 1,200,000 values

Comment: When I change everything to fit 1 channel (grayscale), I get this error: `ValueError: Error when checking : expected flatten_Flatten1_input to have shape [null,7,7,256] but got array with shape [1,800,500,1].`